# Unit of point radius in OpenLayers2

Tags: openlayers-2

What is the unit of measurement for `pointRadius` in the code below:

```
var dotStyle = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
      pointRadius: 5, 
    });
```

I mean what does 5 represent? 5 pixels or 5 mm or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the unit is Pixel,see 
http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Feature/Vector-js.html

{Number} Pixel point radius.